# getting string from MYSQL and using it in Select stament

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get a string from the database and use it in the Select statement .

```
$netpay1="netpay";
$tbp="Paye_deductions";
$tbq="Extra_deductions";

// Connect to server and select databse.
$conn = mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysqli_select_db($conn,"$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Construct our join query
// sending query
```

The code belowe fetches the string from MYSQL database

```
$rql = "Select * FROM $netpay1 WHERE Employee_Number = '$user1'";



// output data of each row
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $rql);
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1, MYSQLI_BOTH);
$Tax1 = $row2["Taxable_Deduction"];
$non = $row2["non_tax_deduction"];
```

After fetching the string i want to use it to Select the items in the string  but it says error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM Paye_deductions "
any ideas on how this can be performed ?

i looked in the database and this is how the string is saved "Company_Car,Housing_Allowance".

```
$result6 =  "SELECT $tax1 FROM $tbp WHERE Employee_Number='$user1' AND Month='$months1' AND Year='$years1'";

$result55 = mysqli_query($conn, $result6);
$row55 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result55, MYSQLI_BOTH);
$sum = array_sum($row55);

if (!$result55) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}

echo $sum;
echo $Tax1;
```

Comment: What do you see if you display the content of your variable `$result6` before you hand it off to `mysqli_query()`? What happens if you stuff it into an interactive MySQL client like phpmyadmin or HeidiSQL?   (@RiggsFolly, look at the second line of code in the question.)

Comment: `$tax1` =/= `$Tax1` thats a definite error

Answer (score -1):

There are mistakes  in your query. Try this:

```
  $rql = "Select * FROM ".$netpay1." WHERE Employee_Number = ".$user1;
```

Whenever you use php variable dont include it in double quotes.

Comment: You do know that `$variables` are automatically expanded if used in a double quoted string dont you?

Comment: In double quotes $variables will be considered as part of string. I think you haven't tried this have you?

Comment: Yes I have, and you are right. Therefore there is nothing wrong _in principal_ with `"Select * FROM $netpay1 WHERE Employee_Number = '$user1'";` assuming the correct variables are used. So there is no need in this case to split the string concatenation up into bits.